# Setting up Team Foundation server with Continuous integration

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, configuration, tfsbuild

I have been trying to Setup TFS with continuous integration on Local Network, where we have 3 developers to check in code.

Which method of deployment should i follow to achieve this

- I found these option

Deploy TFS in several ways: on one server; on many servers; or in one domain or workgroup or across domains.

and are there any tutorials to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup a CI pipeline, it is not necessary to deploy your TFS on several machines. More important is to setup a build controller on a separate machine. With that you end up having the TFS on one machine and the build controller on the other. Also you should customize the build process the way you need it. This really depends on what you want to do, f.e. running multiple build process one after another.

Comment: But how to go about adding other users on a network to TFS in other words how will i add contributor to code in local machine.

Comment: Depends on how your network is setup and on which level you want to add the user (collection-level, project-level, etc.). Can you say something about that?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your patience. I have default collections and it is fine if i can have user on collection level but i could not find a way to create one.

Comment: If you have a small team you can create Windows accounts on your TFS machine and add these Windows Accounts to your collection (via the Web Access interface). If you have something like an Active Directory the process is similar (except that you don't have to create users on your TFS machine).

Comment: I Could not add other computers users Let's say, I have 3 PCs connected via LAN(no Active Directory) ie WorkGroup. In every PC, I have 3 users. So I have these users, PC1\UserA, PC2\UserB, PC3\UserC. I have setup the TFS 2010 Server on PC1. Now how will i add PC2\UserB.
 I could not add windows accounts apart from PC1/user1, PC1/user2, PC1/user3

Comment: I haven't tried your setup before, but from what I read from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507(v=vs.100).aspx) you have to create local accounts on TFS for each user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47948/discussion-between-sureshdeepak-and-horizon-net)